# Weird Distorted Paint Screen When Waking MacBook Air 2017 (High Sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake, screen, screensaver

Once in a while when waking my MacBook Air (from being off the charger and closed to open), I see a weird paint screen flash for a second (probably less then that). It kinda resembles that paint like-screen they show off on the iPhone XS (I don't think there is a connection between the two, but I say this so you can get a example of what it looks like). It also goes away like a screensaver, it like pops out and goes to the lock screen. (when you wake from a screensaver, that motion is what it kinda looks like when it goes away).

What is this that I keep seeing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you had your phone recording it (video) while you attempted to replicate the problem.  It's kinda hard to see from this distance.

Comment: I would love to, but I have some limitations in what I have. Long story short: I don't have a phone, and it is something outside my control. I'll try to get some footage of this, but I might not be able to.